# Error al desplegar archivos war con archivos jasper al servidor

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports, ireport

Estoy desarrollando un aplicativo web en java que contiene reportes hechos en ireport. al ejecutar dentro del entorno de desarrollo me funciona bien, pero al subirlo al servidor tomcat, ejecuto el aplicativo (WAR) desde el servidor no funciona la parte del reporte me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tendría que subir el archivo del reporte que es jasper al servidor tomcat? o como resolvería el error?

Comment: El log te lo está indicando, no encuentra el resource en la ruta especificada si deseas subir a un servidor, deberás indicarle donde está los .jasper, ejemplo puedes colocarlos en C:\miAPP\reportes\ aqui los .jasper , o indicarle si los obtendrá como resources dentro de la aplicación.

Answer (score 2):

Te está dando error porque tienes una ruta fija al reporte, ahí tienes dos alternativas

1. Subirlo al war recomiendo que lo pongas en el directorio web-inf para que no se pongan descargar directamente pero si ser ejecutados si usas maven no te olvides que tendrás que ponerlo como recurso
2. Que lo pongas en una ruta en tu server que se repita en tu local y en el server

La primera te obliga a deployar si cambias reportes para sistemas pequeños esto no importa.

La segunda es mejor porque es lo contrario de la primera

Comment: La segunda te impide tener varias instancias para hacer pruebas. Personalmente prefiero la primera porque cuando haces las cosas en serio (varios entornos, para desarrollo, test, QA, preproducción, producción), el tener toda la aplicación como unos pocos archivos evita muchos problemas ("Ay! He actualizado el jar pero se olvidó pasar el report nuevo!"). Si tienes unos reports muy dinámicos, establece la ruta por configuración o guardalos en una BD, y crea un backoffice para actualizarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes colocar los .jasper en la carpeta resource.

La siguiente página describe como hacerlo.

[resources](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/)